# Parse nested XML in java

Tags: java

I have the XML as below

```
<Result>
   <error><SubTask name="witbe" status="ERROR running Witbe" /></error>
   <error><subtask name="VerifyDataServices" status="FAILURE" /></error>
   .... multiple error tags

</Result>
```

I want to retrieve the entire stuff under the error tag no matter what tag is there inside it. I was trying to parse that with XPath but getting null as the value of error

The code I'm using

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        if (null != inputStream)
        {
            Document doc = db.parse(inputStream);

            XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            String errorTag = "/Result/error";

            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(errorTag).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
            }


        }
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
          Node node = nodeList.item(i);
          if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
              Node childNode = node.getFirstChild();
              System.out.println(childNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name") 
                          + " : " + childNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("status"));
          }
    }
}
```

Above code will print following output:

```
name="witbe" : status="ERROR running Witbe"
name="VerifyDataServices" : status="FAILURE"
```

Do you need these values?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you just putted the all file in a new string called "xml".

```
String[] xmllines = xml.split('\n');

for(int i = 0; i< xmllines.length(); i++){

    if(xmllines[i].startsWith("<error>"){
         xmllines[i] = xmllines[i].replace("<error>", "");
         xmllines[i] = xmllines[i].replace("</error>", "");
    }
    else {
         xmllines[i] = "";
    }

}
```

The result is the xmllines array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int k = 0; k < nodeList.getLength(); k++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(k).getFirstChild();

    System.out.println(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name"));
    System.out.println(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("status"));

}
```